# Redirect users after first login

Tags: redirect, login, front-end

I want to redirect my users to a page after they logged in for the first time.
I also noticed some solutions like a redirect after the user was registered (redirect after first 48 hours) but the problem is that all users are registered already.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use following code to achieve your requirement.

```
//hook when user registers
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    // insert meta that user not logged in first time
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'prefix_first_login', '1');

}

// hook when user logs in
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);

function your_function($user_login, $user) {

    $user_id = $user->ID;
    // getting prev. saved meta
    $first_login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'prefix_first_login', true);
    // if first time login
    if( $first_login == '1' ) {
        // update meta after first login
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'prefix_first_login', '0');
        // redirect to given URL
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```