# Redirect users after register (first login) and force submit post

Tags: redirect, user-registration

I want  redirect users after register and first login to submission page for submit one post (listing), which will be linked to the user's profile. If they don't submit listing, they can't continue to use the whole site (I have multisite).

The first stage works very well following this manual -
[Redirect users after first login](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192671/redirect-users-after-first-login)

How to force not to leave the submit page?

Thanks!